# Adjusting heights of two DTM rasters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

I have two DTM rasters of a forest area. The base heights of the winter DTM must match the base heights of the summer DTM.

How can I adjust them using ArcMap?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: I've only worked with QGIS so far and tried to solve it by using the raster calculator (did not work). Our teacher wants us to solve it using ArcGIS this time & I don't know much about that software. I guess I can activate spatial analyst

Comment: If winter DTM is 'wrong' don't use it?

Comment: Can you isolate the base height areas that must match? In a similar situation for change detection both datasets were +/- 15cm but their mismatch was not constant so I isolated the hard surface areas that should match, entered points (lots of points), subtract one DTM from the other to make a difference raster, used extract values to points to get the difference value assigned to the points, created a Terrain from said points, terrain to raster to make a surface to subtract and then finally subtract the surface from the higher raster which drags down all the other values in between.

Comment: When you say using raster calculator didn't work, how did it not work?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Today I tried again using raster calculator and it worked. Yesterday the result made no sense. (I'm sorry it's difficult for me to express myself in english). The winter DTM is not really wrong; it provides a higher resolution than the summer DTM. But the summer data (DTM & DEM) provide the right heights. My job was to combine winter DTM with summer DEM in order to get an optimized nDOM of the forest area.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your post, this is the situation:

1. The summer DTM values are correct.
2. Some (or all) winter DTM values do not match their corresponding summer values.  Therefore, they are in error and must be corrected to match their corresponding summer values.
3. Once the corrections to the winter data are made, the summer and winter values will be identical.

If my understanding is correct, here's what I'd do:

1. Delete the winter DTM.
2. Copy the summer DTM, naming the new DTM the same as the deleted winter DTM.

Voila! The summer and winter DTMs are now identical, pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: thank you, I finally solved it by using raster calculator!